# WebRTC: one-way video call

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm working on a webRTC solution where only one peer sends video, and the other one just listens. So far, I've managed to do so by calling `getUserMedia()` but not attaching any tracks to the connection, but the browser asks for permission anyway which is misleading, as in fact no tracks from offering side are added to connection.
As `offerToReceive*` options are now deprecated, docs say that the preferred way to achieve this is using transmitters.
I've tried creating an offer on receiving side, adding the transceiver:

```js
con.addTransceiver('video', { direction: 'recvonly' })
```

and on answering side,

```js
const transceivers = con.getTransceivers()
stream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track, i) => {
  transceivers[i].sender.replaceTrack(track)
})
```

but then I get an exception on the offering side

```
Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer.
```

which is true, because somehow the second offer has different `m=video` section IDs, and answering side throws a 701 `STUN server address is incompatible.`.

How do I achieve one-way video calls?

Comment: Simply _don't_ use `getUserMedia` and _don't_ add any tracks to the connection on the listener side…!? It's the `getUserMedia` which causes the permission popup, not the WebRTC connection. And you don't need to add anything to the connection in other to make or receive an offer (anyone correct me on that point if I'm wrong…).

Comment: The exceptions I get represents the case when I do not call `getUserMedia`.

Comment: What docs make claim that this is deprecated? Dubbing it "legacy" and Safari refusing to implement this widely used option is a shame but has not affected real-world usage.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer#parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK looks like I've managed to get it working without the client calling `getUserMedia`.
I guess the problem lays somewhere in the process of renegotiations, since I tried to stick to the "client always offers, server always answers" schema.
Having thoroughly read the MDN, I've got rid of explicit calls to `createOffer` and `createAnswer` and let the browser decide.

More on this on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setLocalDescription
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setRemoteDescription